# How to find polygon in geoJson saved in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, geojson

I got some geoJSON files that I put into a MongoDB base.
The geoJSON schema are standardized, so I expect to do not change it.
The geoJSON files represents tagged defined by a set of area (polygons)
A tag may hold many polygons
Different tags may hold same areas or polygons.

The geoJSON file is like :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5570864ee4b08fb4e548beb6"
    },
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "ida": "2335",
                "name": "myName",                    
                 ...,
                "surf_m2": 13432292
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "MultiPolygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            [
                                -1.366403393656118,
                                47.19539498257428
                            ],
                            [
                                -1.357701323667323,
                                47.19374649592587
                            ],
                            [
                                -1.357566935700819,
                                47.1932311120653
                            ],
                            [
                                -1.357111040694128,
                                47.192966611925904
                            ],
                            ...
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Image I have many documents like this.

How can I query mongoDB in the shell to find area (by name, id or whatever) that are within the polygons available in the base.

I have tryed this :

```
db.Collection.find({"features":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[-1.3545706,47.166627 ]}}}})
```

Or

```
db.runCommand( { geoNear : "Collection" ,near : { type : "Point",coordinates:[-1.3545706,47.166627]},spherical : true }
```

My issue is that I wasn't able to reach the coordinates as it is not directly accessible at root level, but at features.geometry.coordinates.

Help...

Comment: Supported GeoJSON objects for MongoDB are listed and [explained here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/).  Basically the best you can do is break this down to [GeomeryCollection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/geojson/#geometrycollection) objects as FeaturesCollection is not supported.

Comment: @user3561036, ok, so would you do this runtime or by creating a new collection matching more the query ?

Comment: You cannot "do at runtime" because the query options require an "index". This means the collection data already needs to be stored in that form. You either store it in a supported way and let MongoDB do the work, or offload to another service to process the stored data where that does the "grunt work". I like ( reasonably ) big iron database servers to do the grunt myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it runtime, by replacing the GPS position by the one you want.

```
db.CollectionName.find({"features.geometry":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[ -1.346784,47.141102]}}}})
```